# Is it possible to embed a shiny app hosted online into an R-Markdown document?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am looking for a way to include an interactive shiny app in an R-Markdown .html document that I can share with colleagues. Unfortunately, most of these colleagues are not r-savvy, so running the Markdown script themselves is a no-go. I know shiny needs a host machine to run the code in the background, so simply saving the generated .html does not work. But is it possible to, say, deploy the shiny app on shinyapps.io, and somehow embed the url into the R-Markdown document so when the document is opened, it connects automatically to the shinyapps.io link, and displays the app running on the shinyapps server?

Comment: Why don't you just give them the url ?

Comment: I would like to create a fully self-contained, interactive report that does not require navigating to a separate browser or having knowledge of how to run R-scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a html document containing link to your app. An iframe is used to display a webpage in the main one. Create a file `app.html` and write inside:

```
<iframe src="https://www.shinyapps.io/" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```

Or in `rmarkdown` ([documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/include-url.html)) use:

````
```{r, out.width =  "100%"}
knitr::include_app("https://www.shinyapps.io")
```
````

Thanks to @Stéphane Laurent

Comment: or **knitr::include_url/app**

Comment: I tried both options, and both render an empty square. Do you have an idea why that may happen? The app works (I used an R-shiny tutorial code chunk) and I can access it online, so it is running too.

Comment: Please have a look at edited answer